# matplotlib title() not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why is the first title not shown, but the second title is? And how should I fix this? I suspect the problem is that `plt.title('PSBA mRNA')` resets the title before the previous one is shown. But adding `plt.show()` after `plt.title('Viral_load')` introduces other problems with the plots.

```
fig, (ax_viral, ax_psba) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize = (10,5))
fig = sm.graphics.qqplot(residuals_viral, dist=stats.norm, line='45', fit=True, ax=ax_viral)
plt.title('Viral load')
fig = sm.graphics.qqplot(residuals_psba, dist=stats.norm, line='45', fit=True, ax=ax_psba)
plt.title('PSBA mRNA')
plt.show()
```

[QQ plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDmQi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `ax.set_title('title')` method to set title to the axes

```
fig, (ax_viral, ax_psba) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize = (10,5))
fig = sm.graphics.qqplot(residuals_viral, dist=stats.norm, line='45', fit=True, ax=ax_viral)
ax_viral.set_title('Viral load')
fig = sm.graphics.qqplot(residuals_psba, dist=stats.norm, line='45', fit=True, ax=ax_psba)
ax_psba.set_title('PSBA mRNA')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you set the title to the axes instead of `plt.title`:

```
ax_viral.set_title('Viral load')
ax_psba.set_title('PSBA mRNA')
```